# 90s (or earlier) Arthurian book: women training to be witches, evil Merlin and Excalibur called Caliborne

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book that I read in the mid 90s.

It was about 3 sisters meeting Morgan le Fey in modern times and training to be witches. The overall plot assumes the legend if King Arthur was wrong, and Merlin was the evil one.

The three sisters all had one unique power to each of them, one of which was the power to talk to animals. The last notable thing I can think to mention was they called Excalibur by the name Caliborne, claiming that to be the true name of the sword.

I can remember is that the title does not give any hints to the inclusion of an Arthurian legend.

Comment: Apart from Excalibur not being named Caliburne, this sounds a lot like *The Mists of Avalon*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mists_of_Avalon

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen: Granted I read it a long time ago, but I do not remember The Mists of Avalon having any connection to modern times.  A quick glance at the Wikipedia page confirms this.  Though it was my first thought when reading the title of the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about modern times.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this to be one of various books from L.J. Smith's "Night of the Solstice" series. If I'm correct, this actually involves three sisters and one brother.

From the author's homepage (http://www.ljanesmith.net/author/booklist/197-the-night-of-the-solsticeheart-of-valor), note this blurb, in which the sisters are training (one of them under Morgana to become a witch) and one of them does have the power to talk to animals:

"Heart of Valor:
The second book in the trilogy about the adventures of the Hodges-Bradley children. By now, Janie is Morgana’s apprentice, studying to become a sorceress herself, while Alys, against her will, is forced into the role of a sword-wielding hero. Charles is still in love with the mercurial elf Elwyn, and Claudia’s courage is tested along with her ability to talk to animals."

The books were published in 1987 and 1990, which fits the time you remember reading them.

Comment: If this isn't the correct answer, you may want to take a look through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_le_Fay_in_popular_culture#In_literature